# Cannot deploy solution to iOS Device Xamarin Studio

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to deploy this sample:https://github.com/danvanderboom/Xamarin-Forms-TreeView to my iPhone 6 by using Xamarin Studio (5.10.3 for Mac) and I'm getting the following error:

error MT1006: Could not install the application ... on the device : The code was compiled for a different kind of device that the one connected (iPad vs iPhone for example, error: 0xe8000080)

I migrated the iOS project to the latest Xamarin.Forms version.  Supported architectures are set to: ARMV7 + ARM64

Any ideas about what may be going wrong?

Thanks!